# How to optimize performance of DOMXpath

Tags: dom, xpath

I am currently using DOMXpath for extracting information from website but most of the time i get the maximum execution time exceed error. Is there any method that similar to DOMXpath but way more faster?

Comment: You can write slow code in any language, including XPath. If your code is slow, show us your code, and perhaps we can tell you why it is slow. Also, speed depends on the implementation: there are lots of implementations of DOM and XPath, and we'll need to know which one you are using.